Transferring money from phantom wallet to Coinbase not working?
I transferred money into my phantom wallet and put it in various meme coins. Once I took my profits I sent the money to my solona address on my Coinbase account, on phantom wallet it says the transaction was “successful” but when I open my Coin base the money that is supposed to be transferred  isn’t there, I did this all on last Wednesday and it’s a lot of money and I still haven’t received it…. Plz help

If your SOL transfer shows as “successful” in Phantom Wallet but isn’t in Coinbase, check these steps:
1.  Verify Transaction: Use Solscan to confirm the transaction and ensure it was sent to the correct Coinbase SOL address.
2.  Check the Network: Ensure the transfer was sent via the Solana network. Coinbase won’t support funds sent via other networks.
3.  Contact Coinbase Support: If details are correct, reach out to Coinbase with your transaction ID for help.

In my case I’m still figuring out how to solve my problem. I called Coinbase and they said to contact phantom, but phantom don’t have customer service. Other option so I can recover my money ?
